# use reduce function with nested map

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to download files that are in specific folders inside fire store, which is working fine.

My problem is that when mapping over each folder, each downloaded folder (in zip format) contain the accumulate of the previous folders, probably I'm not using the reduce function correctly.

if I don't use reduce function, all downloads are empty.

here is the code:

```
const DownloadFolders = async () => {
  const jszip = new JSZip();
  const storage = getStorage();

  folderNumber.map(async (num: any) => {
    const folder = await listAll(ref(storage, `/folders/folder${num}`));

    const proms = await folder.items
      .map(async (item: any) => {
        const file = await getMetadata(item);
        const fileRef = ref(storage, item.fullPath);
        const fileBlob = await getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((url) => {
          return fetch(url).then((response) => response.blob());
        });
        jszip.file(file.name, fileBlob);
      })
      .reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => currentValue);

    await proms;
    const blob: any =
      folder.items.length !== 0 &&
      (await jszip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }));
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `folder${rot}.zip`);
  });
};
```

What I get is :

- folder1.zip contains file1,
- folder2.zip contain file1 and file2,
- etc...

What I'm looking for is to get:

- folder1.zip contains file1,
- folder2.zip contain file2,
- etc...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) basically returns the accumulated value. So it's accumulating every value and returning as one value.

Comment: i know that, i'm trying to figure out a way to accumulate per folder not per  all of them, like reinitializing or reseting the a counter for each major map()

Comment: unable to interpret your element in `.map()`  What does `map` returns as a list?